# c++ concat files

Tags: c++

I am trying to concatenate two binary files into another output file.
I am using the following code:

```cpp
std::ofstream outFile("file.out", std::ios::ate );
std::ifstream inFile1(getExeDirectory() / "file.in");
std::ifstream inFile2(archive_file);

outFile << inFile1.rdbuf() << inFile2.rdbuf();

std::cout << "Created: '" << out_file << "'" << std::endl;

inFile1.close();
inFile2.close();
outFile.close();

// Delete tmp file
fs::remove(archive_file);

std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
```

The problem I am facing, is that `archive_file` is a temp file, that I need to delete after it has been appended.
My program only copies the first 2-3kb of file.in before printing "Done!" and terminating.

`file.in` is 1.2Mb, while `archive_file` is 4.7kB. The output contains the first 1400 bytes of `file.in`, followed by the first 52 bytes of `archive_file`.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Your theory about the cause of the problem doesn't hold up: the insertion operation does not run asynchronously (none of the iostreams stuff does), and does not return until it is complete.

Comment: @JaMiT infact, I did check both files, `file.in` is 1.2Mb, while `archive_file` is 4.7kB.
The output contains the first 1400 bytes of `file.in`, followed by the first 52 bytes of `archive_file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was, that my files contained null bytes, and I didn't open them in binary mode.
This fixed the issue:

```cpp
std::ofstream outFile("file.out", std::ios_base::binary );
std::ifstream inFile1(getExeDirectory() / "file.in", std::ios_base::binary);
std::ifstream inFile2(archive_file, std::ios_base::binary);
```